# How can i copy a specific table and paste it in a specific part of a doc using google app script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to copy a table that i already have in my doc and paste it in other part of the doc, someone know how to do that?

I'm very new doing this so what i have until now is to copy some table and paste it randomly. I want to copy the table i want not some table and paste it wherever i want not randomly

***Here is the link to my doc ***
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1s2TCspXbjvHVurwhIWSdwJ_hMcZIoLTKj4FAB82nmhM/edit?usp=sharing

***Here is my current code***

```js
function copyBody(){
  var sourcedoc = DocumentApp.openById('1nH84jfwW0-YD4_6LgRQF7MXB7GsWeTomAQK1Foz3BLE');
  var sourcebody = sourcedoc.getBody();
  var tables = sourcebody.getTables();
  var table = tables[0].copy();
  var x = sourcebody.appendTable(table)
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot understand about `I want to copy the table i want not some table and paste it wherever i want not randomly`. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal? In your script, the 1st table is appended to the document body. In this case, for example, you want to use `insertTable` instead of `appendTable`?

Comment: How can i copy the last table of my doc? yes i want to insert the table i already copy between my content

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to copy a table in the source Document to the destination Document.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

In this answer, the following sample situation is used.

- There are 2 Google Documens which are source Document and destination Document.
- The table is put to the source Document.
- The destination Document has a text of `{{replace}}` as the paragraph.
- When the sample script is run, the table in the source Document is copied and pasted to the destination Document by replacing `{{replace}}` with the table.

#### Sample script:

Before you run the script, please copy and paste `{{replace}}` to the destination Document. And then, please run the script.

```
function myFunction() {
  const sourceDocId = "###";  // Please set the source Document ID.
  const destinationDocId = "###";  // Please set the destination Document ID.

  const srcDoc = DocumentApp.openById(sourceDocId);
  const srcTable = srcDoc.getBody().getTables()[0].copy();

  const dstDoc = DocumentApp.openById(destinationDocId);
  const dstBody = dstDoc.getBody();
  const find = dstBody.findText("{{replace}}");
  if (find) {
    const child = find.getElement().getParent();
    const childIndex = dstBody.getChildIndex(child);
    dstBody.insertTable(childIndex, srcTable);
    find.getElement().removeFromParent();  // <--- Modified
  }
}
```

#### References:

- [getChildIndex(child)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#getchildindexchild)
- [insertTable(childIndex, table)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#insertTable(Integer,Table))

Comment: Your answer its almost perfect the problem is that give me this error `Exception: Can't remove the last paragraph in a document section` in this line `child.removeFromParent();`

Comment: @Rinzler21 Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? If that didn't resolve your issue, I apologize again.